# Getting the previous value on a RichEditableText change event in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I'm listening for the `Change` (and `Changing`) event of a `RichEditableText` control. I want to get the text *before* the change. To be clear, I don't want to undo, simply to inspect the previous value.

I'm sure there's a way to do this somewhere inside the `FlowOperation` object, but I can't find it.

```
protected function titleLabel_changingHandler(event:TextOperationEvent):void
{
    // How do I get the previous value? 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the initial value of the control is empty, initialize a String variable to the empty string.  Toward the end of your handler method, assign the NEW value of the control to this variable.  Thus, the next time your handler is called, the variable now holds the OLD value.

Comment: naturally, I can store the value externally, but that's kind of missing the point. The Change event must have some way of getting at that information...

Comment: My interpretation of the API is that this can't be done. TextOperationEvent has the standard event props: bubbles, cancelable, currentTarget, operation, target, and type; and adds only the FlowOperation as you mention. But the FlowOperation will only tell you what kind of change occured via the sub-types insert, delte, cut, paste, split and undo. I could be wrong, but I don't see anything that even suggests what you are looking for.

Comment: What makes me think it's possible is that generation data in the flow. Otherwise I don't see the point in having it. There's gotta be a way to use it to examine the previous generation...

Answer (score 0):

While this is a very old question, I'd rather Googlers didn't go away empty-handed.

```
protected function changingHandler(e:TextOperationEvent):void {
    trace("Value before change: "+e.operation.textFlow.getText());
}
```